# how make the opentsdb store duplicate data

Tags: java, duplicate-data, opentsdb

I have three duplicate records with the same timestamp, the same metric, the same tags etc. Because of concurrence. When I had stored them in opentsdb, only the last one record had been stored, others had been covered. But I want all the records can be stored. how can I resolved this problem, thank you very much.

Comment: You can an add an enumeration tag at the client to differentiate the samples, e.g. tag-version=1. If key and time are the same, what's the meaning of different values?

Comment: eg. [{timestamp=123456,value=1},{timestamp=123456,value=2},{timestamp=123456,value=3}], opentsdb  can not store all them, but I want.

Comment: What's the meaning of different values with the same timestamp?

Comment: because of the concurrence, one server may receive multi requests at the same time, the value is the process time of every request, so  different values with the same timestamp

Comment: Still not clear, but i digress.

Comment: You can sum processing times for multiple requests that occurred during the same millisecond at the source. Sum(process_time).

Comment: I have the same problem and looking for a solution. 
I'm processing events at the rate of 40 per second. Some of these events can have the same epoch time which might be overwritten.